# Accessing inner elements in xml file from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appcmd>
   <APP path="/" APP.NAME="test1" pool="Pool1">
      <application name="app1">
         <virtualDirectory />
         <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\test" />
      </application>
   </APP>

   <APP path="/" APP.NAME="test1" pool="Pool1">
      <application name="app1">
         <virtualDirectory />
         <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\test" />
      </application>
   </APP>
</appcmd>
```

Below is the code trying to access application name attribute:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
mydoc = minidom.parse('ex1.xml')
apps = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('APP')
print(mydoc.nodeName)
print(mydoc.firstChild.tagName)
for app in apps:
    app_path = app.getAttribute('path')
    print(app_path)
    application_pool = app.getAttribute('application')['name']
    print(application_pool)
```

i am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
#document
  File "C:/py372/files/readxml1.py", line 9, in <module>
    application_pool = app.getAttribute('application')['name']
appcmd
TypeError: string indices must be integers
/

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can any one help me how to access application and virtualDirectory attributes

Comment: Suggest you switch from minimdom to ElementTree - then you can use `find()` and `findall()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
application_pool = app.getAttribute('application')['name']
```

i used code below as there is no attribute `name` in node `application`, first you need to find node that contains it with `.getElementByTagName()` and then you can access it attributes.

```
for names in app.getElementsByTagName('application'):
        print(names.getAttribute('name'))
```

this gave me output like:

```
#document
appcmd
/
app1
/
app1
```

P.S. It's my first answer :) hope it's good enough :)

Comment: If I use for loop, How to get only firstchild tag attributes ?

Comment: You can use: `name = app.getElementByTagName('application')[0]` instead of loop and `print(names.getAttribute('name'))`